# Use regex to parse this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex is so confusing to me. Can someone explain how to parse this url, so that I just get the number `7`?

```
'/week/7'

var weekPath = window.location/path = '/week/7';
weekPath.replace(/week/,""); // trying to replace week but still left with //7/
```

Comment: `'/week/7'.split('/')[2]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fixing your regex:**

Add `\/` to your regex as below. This will capture the `/` before and after the string `week`.

```js
var weekPath = '/week/7';
var newString = weekPath.replace(/\/week\//,"");

console.dir(newString); // "7"
```

---

**Alternative solution with `.match()`:**
To grab just the number at the end of the string with regex:

```js
var weekPath = '/week/7';
var myNumber = weekPath.match(/\d+$/);// \d captures a number and + is for capturing 1 or more occurrences of the numbers

console.dir(myNumber[0]); // "7"
```

**Read up:**

- [`String.prototype.replace()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [`String.prototype.match()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 6):

Place it as string and not regex

```
weekPath.replace("/week/","");
=> "7"
```

**Difference ?**

When the the string is delimited with `/ /`, then the string is taken as a regex pattern, which will only replace `week` for you.

But when delimited by `" "`, it is taken as raw string, `/week/`

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> weekPath.replace(/week/,""); // trying to replace week but still left with //7/
> ```

Here you matched the characters `week` and replaced them, however your pattern doesn't match the slash characters.  The two slashes in your source code are simply part of the syntax in JavaScript for creating a regex object.

Instead:

```
weekPath = weekPath.replace(/\/week\//, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use regex for this.  You can just get the pathname and split on the '/' character.

Assuming the url is http://localhost.com/week/7:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var num = path[1]; //7
```